# Required field for the textbox when the textbox is show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to give required field for show/hide the textbox when the textbox is shown. when a particular radio button is checked a textbox is shown. When the particular textbox is show it should be a required field. It should not be empty.

Show/hide of textbox works fine for me. How can I give required field for the textbox

Show/hide textbox works fine. Required field doesn't work

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".text").hide();
    $("#presentation").click(function () {
    $(".text").show();
    });
    $("#participant").click(function () {
    $(".text").hide();
   });
 });
 function getResults(){
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="events" 
  id="participant" value="Participant" required >Participant</label>
   <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="events" 
     id="presentation" value="Presentation" 
      onClick="getResults()">Presentation</label>

        </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-6 text">
      <label>Title of Presentation:</label><span style="color:red";>* 
      </span>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" >
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: By required field, if you mean `*` symbol, it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.attr()` to set the attribute and `.removeAttr()` to remove the attribute when the element is not displayed:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#presentation").click(function () {
      $(".text").show();
      $("#title").attr("required", true);
  });
  $("#participant").click(function () {
      $(".text").hide();
      $("#title").removeAttr("required");
  });
});
```

```css
.text{display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="events" id="participant" value="Participant" required="">Participant</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="events" id="presentation" value="Presentation">Presentation</label>

  <div class="form-group col-md-6 text">
    <label>Title of Presentation:</label><span style="color:red" ;>*
    </span>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".text").hide();
  $("#presentation").click(function() {
    $(".text").show();
    $(".text").attr('required',true);
  });
  $("#participant").click(function() {
    $(".text").hide();
    $(".text").attr('required',false);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add required to your input field

```
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" required>
```

Comment: I checked the same But when textbox is hidden the form doesnt get submitted

Comment: do you mean the form not submit when your textbox is hidden?

Comment: yes. When the user clicks on "Presentation" radio button the textbox has to be displayed and has to be required field